# Javascript textContent is not working in IE8 or IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I need to add 2 cell content of a table and display it. Below JavaScript command works fine in chrome or IE10. **But not working in IE8 or 7**.

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").textContent).toFixed(2);
```

It results,

> **NaN**

Could you please tell me what is the **equivalent command in IE7 or IE8** to read cell content of a table and convert it to float then add..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Node.textContent) is not supported by IE7/8. The latter has a different property called innerText which returns the text contents of a DOM node.

Here is how to use both:

```
var text  = e.item.textContent || e.item.innerText;
alert(text);
```

**NOTE:** e is html element

Comment: Element which you want to retrieve text from DOM.

Comment: Thanks... What is the different between innerText & textContext ? does it make any difference in any browsers ?

Comment: click on the link mentioned in answer.. you have more details there

Comment: since empty string is considered "falsy" by || operator, I would suggest using `'textContent' in e.item ? e.item.textContent: e.item.innerText` just to be safe

Answer (score 0):

Unknowns answer is completely correct.  That said if you are using jQuery, you can simply do `$(element).text()`