# jQuery Grab Text inside a Tag in String Format and Add to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string which is like

```
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
 industry.<grab> First Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
 the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Second Item</grab>Lorem
 Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
 industry.<grab>Third Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
 the printing and typesetting industry.
```

now I need to grab all text between the `<grab>....</grab>` tags and add them two an array. I tried this but it didnt go through

```js
var data = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab> First Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Second Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Third Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.';

var array = $('<grab>').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
$('body').append(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can you please let me know how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not DOM elements actually, so probably regex would help you.

```js
var data = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab> First Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Second Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Third Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.';
var r = /<grab>(.*?)<\/grab>/g;
var grabs = data.match(r).map(function(x){
   return x.replace(r,'$1');
});
console.log(grabs);
```

Comment: Thanks nicael but this is also returning the `grab` tags as well?

Comment: @Beh If you consider it to be the best answer, please click the checkmark.

Comment: Sure I was just waiting for 10 Min!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, despite regular expressions being an option, is to simply use DOM parsing (it doesn't seem to matter if the element-type is custom or otherwise):

```
var data = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry <grab> First Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Second Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Third Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',

    // creating a <div> element with the data string
    // as its innerHTML:
    elem = $('<div />',{
      'html' : data
    }),

    // using find() to retrieve the <grab> elements from
    // within the newly-created <div>, and using map()
    array = elem.find('grab').map(function () {
      // ...to return the trimmed text of each
      // found element:
      return this.textContent.trim();

      // converting the map to an Array:
      }).get();

// appending the joined array (joining the array together
// with a comma-white-space sequence) to the <body>:    
$('body').append(array.join(', '));
// => First Item, Second Item, Third Item
```

```js
var data = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry <grab> First Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Second Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Third Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    
    elem = $('<div />',{
      'html' : data
    }),
    array = elem.find('grab').map(function () {
      return this.textContent.trim();
      }).get();

$('body').append(array.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I learned so many things from this one simple answer.  Are all the JavaScript/jQuery methods used here cross browser compatible?

Comment: They should be, and to my knowledge they are (with the exception of 'old IE' (IE versions 8 and below) due to jQuery's lack of support for those browsers in the 2.x branch. Although I think all the methods used are available in the later branches of the 1.x

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18326717/5076162 says that textContent is not viable in ie7/8.  Please update your code.