# JSON style returns object object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

From [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37887133/5076162) I discovered the power of JavaScript Object Notation (JSON).  In trying to fool around with it, so as to get a better grasp of its utility I tried applying a few additional attributes to the element.  My question is how can I get JSON to parse a nested node as a string, instead of an object object?  As a follow-up to that question, what is the correct syntax to nest CSS styles within JSON declarations?

The following **does** work:

`'style': "width: 200px; color: #ACE"`

This does **not** work (returns object object) but I would like it to work (is there some syntax that could achieve this?).

```
'style': [{
   'width': '200px'
}]
```

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/37887133/5076162

var data = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry <grab> First Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Second Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Third Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',


  // creating a <div> element with the data string
  // as its innerHTML:
  elem = $('<div />', {
    'html': data,
    'title': "myClass",
    'style': "width: 200px; color: #ACE",
    //'style': [{
    //  'width': '200px'
    //}]
  }),

  // using find() to retrieve the <grab> elements from
  // within the newly-created <div>, and using map()
  array = elem.find('grab').map(function() {
    // ...to return the trimmed text of each
    // found element:
    return this.textContent.trim();

    // converting the map to an Array:
  }).get();

// appending the joined array (joining the array together
// with a comma-white-space sequence) to the <body>:    
$('body').append(array.join(', '));
// => First Item, Second Item, Third Item
elem.appendTo($('body'));
console.log(JSON.stringify($('div').attr('style')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `'css':{

'width': '200px'

}`

Comment: You seem to confuse JavaScript objects with JSON (understandably because of the name). What you are passing as second argument to `$` is not JSON, it's an object (runtime) / object literal (source code). JSON is language-independent textual *data format*.

Comment: Hi Felix, I'm reading, http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/ now so your comment might make more sense soon after I finish it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `style` can only handle string non-string value it will apply `toString()`. You need to use `css` in jQuery, which can handle object also.

As per [jQuery documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) :

> ***Important:*** If the second argument is passed, the HTML string in the first argument must represent a simple element with no attributes. As of jQuery 1.4, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: val, **css**, html, text, data, width, height, or offset.

```
'css':{ 'width': '200px' }
```

```js
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/37887133/5076162

var data = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry <grab> First Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Second Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<grab>Third Item</grab>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',


  // creating a <div> element with the data string
  // as its innerHTML:
  elem = $('<div />', {
    'html': data,
    'title': "myClass",
    'css': {
      'width': '200px',
      'color':'#ACE'
    }
  }),

  // using find() to retrieve the <grab> elements from
  // within the newly-created <div>, and using map()
  array = elem.find('grab').map(function() {
    // ...to return the trimmed text of each
    // found element:
    return this.textContent.trim();

    // converting the map to an Array:
  }).get();

// appending the joined array (joining the array together
// with a comma-white-space sequence) to the <body>:    
$('body').append(array.join(', '));
// => First Item, Second Item, Third Item
elem.appendTo($('body'));
console.log(JSON.stringify($('div').attr('style')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great documentation.

Answer (score 1):

So close! It is:

```
'css':{ 'width': '200px' }
```

Comment: Hi Ben this is not correct... It is the same issue that I outlined.  It returns `[object object]`.  Does this work in non-jQuery JavaScript?  Please provide a fiddle example (so that I can grasp the concept).