# When ajax success - ajaxComplete is not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When the ajax query is successful - the ajaxcomplete (wrapped in a callbackfunction - click-event) is not fired.

When it, on the other side, is not successful (.error) the ajaxComplete works very well.

To make it even more complicated - heres a more detailed truth about this issue:

1) this is true for firefox and IE. When it comes to Chrome - AjaxComplete is actually fired when ajax success BUT it acts slowly to execute the code within the function.

Very greatful for help

**ajax function**

```
 function fetch_customer_data_from_db(zipcode_string, email_string, query_done, query_fail) {

    var theUrl = "http://mysecretwebpage/json_create.asp";
    $.ajax({
        url: theUrl,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (response) {

            fadeout_email_field();

            query_done = 1;

            $('#cust_date_of_birth').css('display', 'none');
            $('#customer_data_field_text').css('display', 'block');
            $('#validation_message_email').css('visibility', 'hidden');

            var customer_data = response.customerdata;
            customer_data.forEach(function (custdata) {

                document.getElementById("cfname").textContent = custdata.fname; 
                document.getElementById("clname").textContent = custdata.lname; 
                document.getElementById("cadress").textContent = custdata.street; 
                document.getElementById("czipc").textContent = custdata.zipcode; 
                document.getElementById("clocation").textContent = custdata.location; 
                document.getElementById("cemail").textContent = custdata.email; 
                document.getElementById("cmobile").textContent = custdata.mobile; 
            });
        },

        error: function() {

            if (!query_fail) {


                $('#cust_date_of_birth').css('display', 'block');

                $('#validation_message_email').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                query_fail = 1;
                fadeout_email_field();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**click-functions (callbacks)**

if ajax error (here ajaxcomplete works)

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function() {

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {

        $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
           alert("ajax error!!!");
         });
 }
```

if ajax success (ajaxComplete is not fired)

```
$('#button_change_cdata').click(function() {

  $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {   
     alert("ajax success");
  });

});
```

Comment: please read the output of your javascript console, and add this info to your question

Comment: I dont think it is the problem... Maybe be a typo from your cut'n paste on SO... But your string is not closed here `var theUrl = "http://mysecretwebpage/json_create.asp` Add `";`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - thanks, fixed it - yes it due to "cut'n paste"

Comment: Great. Then, I would try a `console.log("Ajax success");` in the success callback... Check your console.

Comment: Put your `click` and `change` functions inside your error and success callback (in the last lines) instead.

Comment: Your last edit about IE and FF is usefull. I found this:  textContent is not supported by IE7/8. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18326717/2159528

Comment: I also found this interesting reading : http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - thanks - will look into this

Comment: @PeterDarmis - yes I did but nothing is changed :-( ... thanks anyway

Comment: That was a quick answer sorry for that. Basically you should not have a problem with ajaxComplete if in your ajax code you used `complete` instead of `success`. You see there is a small difference on those two and i basically understand now the error. Please try `ajaxSuccess` instead of `ajaxComplete` and i will setup my answer.

Comment: What i mean is that if your button with id `#button_change_cdata` is visible upon ajax `success` shouldn't it be bound to `ajaxSuccess` event instead? Therefore can you please provide some more html in order not to guess?

Comment: @PeterDarmis - the answer did not solve it - I think the problem may that i put the ajaxComplete or ajaxSuccess function in the click-event itself. Since I am new to scripting languages (migrating from c and java) and not the least ajax - how could I put the ajaxComplete-function in the fetch_customer_data_from_db-function? just add "ajaxSuccess" to the ajax signature, after error: ?

Comment: Put the `click` and `change` event inside the `ajaxSuccess` and `ajaxError` accordingly.

Comment: @java please check the edited answer i think this will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you use `ajaxComplete` along with a `success` and an `error` callback. To be more accurate you should use `ajaxSuccess` and `ajaxError`.

> **ajaxComplete**: Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete.
>
> **ajaxSuccess**: Attach a function to be executed whenever an Ajax request completes **successfully**.
>
> **ajaxError**: Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete with an error

For your `ajaxSuccess` and `ajaxError` handlers try the following:

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function() {
    $('#checkbox1').on("change",function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
           alert("ajax error!!!");
        }
    });
});
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function() {   
    $('#button_change_cdata').on("click",function() {
           alert("ajax success");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Ryan thanks for the link but i am missing the point. In case you mean that  using `ajaxComplete` could provide the ajax response, the last two examples on the link you provided are mostly relevant. There are differences between `success`,`error` and `complete` ( If you want we could discuss the differences ). That is why i answered as above.