# Internet Explorer does not execute some if-cases in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am creating a html file with xslt. I have some JavaScript code to filter some rows of tables. On Internet Explorer 11 some specific if-cases of my JavaScript are not being executed and I don't know why as there is no error in my devolopment console.
Below you can see some JavaScript code with commands for the executed and not executed if-cases.

If I change `if (i > 2 && modelRange.textContent != rows[i - 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].textContent) {` to `if ( i > 2)` it will execute the if-case. So it has to be a problem with `.textContent` or `.getElementsByTagName` but I don't know why and I don't know how to change that as there is no error and it is working with Firefox.

I also have included `console.log(rows)`.

JavaScript:

```
function test_internet_explorer() {

    // Variables
    var table, checkBox, filterCheckBox, filterDropDown, rows, cells, secret, modelRange, dropdown, rowCount;
    dropdown = document.getElementById('modelRangeDropdown');
    table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    rowCount = table.rows.length; 
    checkBox=document.getElementById('identicalSecrets');
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");    
    console.log(rows)       
    filterCheckBox = checkBox.checked; 
    filterDropDown = dropdown.value;
    var index = 0; 


    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
        var row = rows[i];
        cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
        modelRange = cells[0] || null; 
        secret = cells[3]; 

        // does not execute
        if (i > 2 && modelRange.textContent != rows[i - 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].textContent) {
            rows[i - 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].firstChild.nodeValue = "-";
            alert('script loaded');
        }

        // does execute
        if (i === rowCount - 1) { 
            rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].firstChild.nodeValue = "-";
        }

        // does not execute
        if (i > 2 && modelRange.textContent === rows[i - 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].textContent) {
            rows[i - 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].firstChild.nodeValue = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].textContent;
        }
    }

}
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head><title>Secrets</title></head>

<body onload="test_internet_explorer();">

<table id="myTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="150" style="background-color:e2e2e2"></col>         
        </colgroup>
        <tr  style ="background-color:a5a5a5">
            <th rowspan="2">plane
                <select id="modelRangeDropdown" onchange="test_internet_explorer()">
                     <option selected="selected">All</option>
                     <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane">
                        <option>
                         <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                        </option>
                     </xsl:for-each>                    
                </select>                   
            </th>   
            <th colspan="2" width="330">date</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Secret
                <input type="checkbox" id="identicalSecrets" onchange="test_internet_explorer()"></input>
                <label for="identicalSecrets">hide identical secrets</label>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th align="center" style="background-color:a5a5a5">begin</th>
            <th align="center" style="background-color:a5a5a5">end</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane/trigger">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="../Name"/></td>
                <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="secret"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test_internet_explorer.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Just as a curiosity, is there any hyphen in that text value?

Comment: Can you add some HTML that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Not sure about IE11 but check this [Javascript textContent is not working in IE8 or IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18326717/387194)

Comment: I have added some html code and yes there are hyphens in the text value.

Comment: That is still no [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The if-cases test the content of a table, so without knowing this content we can't do anything. That said, I do notice some HTML problems. [<col>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) and [<input>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) should not have end tags. I don't believe this is related to your problem though.

Comment: This is xslt code

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that those elements should not have closing tags.

Comment: Anyway, I would assume the browser operates on the result of the XSLT transform, not the original XSLT document. So you would need to show us the finished HTML, as KIKO is telling you. You can of course see it via your browser's tools

Comment: I can not remove the closing tags as the xslt code will throw errors. I think I have solve my problem by using ``innerText`` instead of ``textContent`` as I do not need to read content of <script...> oder <style...> where innerText does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case one possible solution is to use `innerText` instead of `textContent` if problems occur on IE11 by using `textContent`.